# Session creation by web application on first request

Tags: jsp, session, servlets, jstl

I am confused about a concept generally we create a session by HttpSession in the servlet.

A. Suppose a user requests the index.jsp page of my web app will the server automatically create a session for the user even when I haven't created a session by HttpSession explicitly.

B. For the links in the index page if I am using `<c:url />` jstl tag for the links but haven't created the session explicitly what will the tags return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A. Unless you've explicitely configured the JSP page to avoid creating a session, a session will be created.

B. It will generate a URL. That's what the c:url tag does. The fact that there is or isn't a session doesn't change anything (except if URL-rewriting is necessary, in which case the session ID will be stored inside the URL, if a session exists).